# Adding extra fields by add button

Tags: javascript, html

This query of adding extra fields by add button is working on Google chrome, but not in Internet explorer. Please help me to work it out in IE 11.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>    
        function add_field() 
        {
            var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0],
            input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            input.setAttribute('name', 'item');
            form.appendChild(input);
        };
    </script>



    <form name="input" method="get">
        <div class="ui-input-text">
            <input type="text" name="item"><br>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <button type="button" onclick="add_field

    ()">ADD</button><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: in IE9 it's working fine.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Why do you use a global variable `input` instead of a local variable?

Comment: It works fine for me with this jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/QVu8k/

Comment: what happen to your title??

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, internet explorers (of various versions) have issues assigning the "name" attribute to elements.  I found the following custom method works for anything:

```
Element.prototype.customAttribute=function(customname, customvalue){
var z=document.createAttribute(customname);
z.value=customvalue;
this.setAttributeNode(z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is working fine, although you need to allow it to run scripts on the site. Internet Explorer will block the script until the user confirm that he/she wants it to run.

> internet explorer prevented this webpage from running scripts or activex controls

I used Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 64-bit. No errors occurred and everything functioned.